# Wrapping a Class<?> type generics error

Tags: java, generics

I'm not following why this code shows this compile error.

Error is:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from TestClass.Wrapper<List<capture#1-of ?>> to TestClass.Wrapper<List<?>>`

Code is below.

```
package test.cls;

import java.util.List;

public class TestClass
{
    static abstract class Wrapper<A>
    {
        public abstract A wrapped();
    }

    public static <A> Wrapper<A> wrap(final A val)
    {
        return new Wrapper<A>()
        {
            public A wrapped()
            {
                return val;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final List<?> list = null;
        final Class<?> c = null;
        final Wrapper<List<?>> wrapList = wrap(list); // Error here
        final Wrapper<Class<?>> wrapC = wrap(c); // Error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to instantiate an abstract class?

Comment: @TheEwook No, the OP's returning an anonymous class instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler's generic type inferrence is choking on the nested wildcard captures. You need to explicitly specify the type arguments:

```
final Wrapper<List<?>> wrapList = TestClass.<List<?>>wrap(list);
final Wrapper<Class<?>> wrapC = TestClass.<Class<?>>wrap(c);
```